# codeigniter form not submitting to method in controller

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, submit

I see a strange behaviour on my test server. In my localhost the application works fine. Once I upload codeigniter to test server update *config.php/database.php* and try to login, particular method is not being called.

`$_POST` array has values. index method is being called successfully. I have loaded all helper files in autoload.

```
<form class="form-signin" action="http://hostname/index.php/welcome/logincheck"  method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
<label for="name">I am a </label>
<select class="form-control" name="role">
   <option value="student">Student</option>
   <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>       
</select><br />
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Any thoughts?

Logincheck Method

```
public function logincheck()
{
    echo "login check function called";

    $this->load->library('session');
        $username=$this->input->post('username');
    $password=$this->input->post('password');
    $role = $this->input->post('role');
    $validity = $this->homefunctions->validate($username,$password,$role);
        if($validity[1])
    { 
     $data=array(
            'username'=>$username,
            'lname'=>$validity[0]['fname'],
            'fname'=>$validity[0]['lname'],
            'role'=>$validity[0]['role'],
            'id'=>$validity[0]['id'],
            'is_logged_in'=> true
        );
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                if($role=="teacher")
                   header('Location:/sch/teacher/index');
                else
                   header('Location:/sch/student/index');

                }

    else{
        $data['message']='Username/Password/Role is wrong';
        $data['main_content']='home1';
            $this->load->view('templates/hometemplate',$data); 
        }

  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the action page url is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "not being called. " ? does it show any kind of error ? Please check for controller and method by putting "http://hostname/index.php/welcome/logincheck" directly into browser ?

Comment: Action page url is correct. I have placed 2 echos. one in index method other in logincheck method. Only index echo works. Live url is : http://ssbj.ahadh.com/  username:teacher and password:teacher.

Comment: Can you share the code for welcome controller

Comment: You should use this action url-`http://ssbj.ahadh.com/index.php/welcome/index/logincheck`

Comment: Please show logincheck method. Because you are transferring the page back to same page. Either you should transfer to different method or there should be condition in same method (logincheck() ) to stop coming back to same page if everthing is correct. You are missing something.

Comment: I have added logincheck method above.

Comment: Please check that you are getting some data in variable "$validity[1]" or print the array before "if" condition and use exit. If you still face error use "echo var_dump($validity[1])" for conformation.

Comment: At least echo should work in logincheck method.I had echoed and var_dump of $validation. Nothing happens.

Comment: There is some thing wrong with the if condition that you are using for checking "$validity[1]". Please use "echo '<pre>'; print_r($validity); exit;". Put it as comment. Also, display the error message "$data['message']" some where on the page.

Comment: I created one more method test. Added var_dump($_POST) and changed action to test method. Still it gives the same behaviour.May be PHP configuration or CI configuration ?

Comment: I solved the issue !!!! I set URI_ROUTING to AUTO Thanks all